# How to differentiate 24 Bit PNG and 32 Bit PNG file?

Tags: png, rgb, image-format

When image is encoded in PNG format, it can be encoded either in 24 bit format (rgb) or in 32 bit format (argb). Both the files appear as .png files. Then how it is possible to differentiate these two types of png files?

To make it more clear, If I am downloading PNG image files from internet how can check in which format it is encoded.

**OS:** Windows 8

Comment: Hi there! I just found this question has been asked (and answered) for Mac in superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/148661/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-png-file-is-24-bit-color-or-32-bit-color-on-mac-os-x Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Yisela I checked your link, but it is specifically for mac OS.And I am using window OS too. Do I need to include information about my OS in my question ?

Comment: A 32 bit .png file has an alpha channel and might have transparent parts, although the latter is not required - so any software that is able to show this information would tell you.

Comment: And for the records, identify is part of ImageMagick on the Windows platforms.

Comment: ImageMagick is new to me. I went through their downloads link just now. There are different versions, based on OS and also based on bits per pixel. In my case I require 32 bits per pixel and that is not there.

Comment: Uh, you are looking for the basic *8 bits per pixel* versions. It's stated awkward -- what they mean is there is a separate suite of programs for super high color depths. Your color depth is 8 bpp *per channel*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this question was asked over a year ago but I stumbled on this post while searching for the answer myself. I found the answer on a different site so I thought I'd share it here.

You can find this information under the Details tab in File Properties. So far it seems to work for files that are natively identified by Windows as an image.

Identify bit depth for image files on Windows:

```
*Right click* image file > Properties > Details > Bit depth
```

[image: Identify image bit depth on Windows]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE, Shimothy! Great first answer. :)